# How can one manually create an Apache request object?

Tags: perl, apache, unit-testing, mod-perl, embperl

Is there a good API that would allow someone to create an object of [`Apache`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache) class?

The class itself seems to lack a constructor; and synopsis wasn't very helpful. My suspicion is that it's somehow done via sublcass, e.g. `Apache::Request`?

The context is I'm trying to write a test for a module which uses Embperl's [`$HTML::Embperl::req_rec`](http://perl.apache.org/embperl/pod/doc/Embperl.-page-5-.htm#sect_22) variable (more specifically, calls the `uri()` method on an object contained in it). The variable, upon examination, contains an object with `ref($req_rec) eq 'Apache'`.

**NOTE**: I'm specifically asking about constructing a REAL (though not necessarily fully functional) object. **NOT** mocking it (which I obviously easily can do and probably will end up doing anyway).

Comment: have you looked in Embperl's test suite? Maybe there you can find a solution to your problem. Emberl's tests somehow create server processes for testing purposes, but I don't remember any details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can create `Apache::Request` objects, period. The intent is for them to be created for you by the mod_perl runtime -- they're internally bound to structures within the Apache process which may not be possible to create from perl.

If you're only doing relatively simple things with the object, you may be able to get a `CGI` object to do the same job. If anything complex is going on, though, there's probably little alternative besides mocking the object or testing within a live Apache instance.

Comment: I decided to stop flopping around and mocked the thing.